# what is different in excel formula start with = and +

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Do these two formula will give different output...?
    =len()
    +len()
i use len just for example, for all formulas.
and what are differences in these two formulas.

Comment: Those two formulas are the same - you will notice that when you enter the 2nd one into Excel, it will automatically convert it to: "=+LEN()". This is because Excel allows you to start a formula with '=', '+', or '-', but after entry Excel wants the "=" to show that its a formula cell, not just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both provide same result only.

= or + when pressed initially it will intimate excel to treat that entry as formula instead of considered as text or number.